# Radio button onclick not working

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have 3 radio buttons that will display certain jobs from a list depending on which button is clicked. I used to use a search button to run the search code. So the user would select a radio button then click search. But now I have removed the search button and I want the radio buttons to call the search function when clicked.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label id="lblAll" runat="server">All</label>
      <input type="radio" name="rbl_filter" runat="server" id="rbAll" onclick="btnSearch_Click" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label id="lblCollections" runat="server">Collections</label>              
      <input type="radio" name="rbl_filter" runat="server" id="rbCollections" checked="true"  onclick="btnSearch_Click"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label id="lblDeliveries" runat="server">Deliveries</label>
      <input type="radio" name="rbl_filter" runat="server" id="rbDeliveries" onclick="btnSearch_Click" />                                                
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I added the same onclick code that the search button was using. But nothing happens when I click the radio buttons

Comment: You don't need a onClick if you add the event handler in your Code Behind file

Comment: You have to handle it in codebehid as your code seems to be onclick not onclientclick and you have html control not asp. Please check

Comment: @DieVeenman I have a search function in the code behind protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e). How do I call it when a radio button is selected?

Comment: @Padmanaban  I have a search function in the code behind protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e). How do I call it when a radio button is selected?

Comment: Add "handles btnSearch.Click" behind it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use () after your function name

this is what you want

```js
       function btnSearch_Click() {
         alert("hello");
       }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label id="lblAll" runat="server">All</label>
      <input type="radio" name="rbl_filter" runat="server" id="rbAll" onclick="btnSearch_Click();" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label id="lblCollections" runat="server">Collections</label>
      <input type="radio" name="rbl_filter" runat="server" id="rbCollections" checked="true" onclick="btnSearch_Click();" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label id="lblDeliveries" runat="server">Deliveries</label>
      <input type="radio" name="rbl_filter" runat="server" id="rbDeliveries" onclick="btnSearch_Click();" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**and for [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q9v8wu46/)**

Comment: I have a search function in the code behind protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
onclick="btnSearch_Click();"
```

You need to have the parenthesis.

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/y9vn5fow/1/

Answer (score 0):

Go to your code behind, then add this to your EventHandler:

```
btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) handles btnSearch.Click
```

No need to add a onClick parameter to your HTML tag

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call your buttonclick event onclick of radio button.

For Example:

Hide your button if necessary.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="btnSeach_Click" style="display:none" />

<input type="radio" name="rbl_filter" runat="server" id="rbAll" onclick="searchClick(); return false;" />
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function searchClick()
 {
    document.getElementById('<%= btnSearch.ClientID %>').click();
 }
</script>
```

Hope it would helps you!

Answer (score 0):

`<label onclick="red()"><input type="radio" name="colors" id="red">Red</label>`

or
 
`<label onclick="red()"><input type="radio" name="colors" id="red"></label>
<label for="red">Red</label>`

```
<script>
function red(){
 alert('i am red');
}
</script>
```

if you want to call onclick function on radio button then you can use like this, it will work for you

Note: we have to call on function on label instead of radio button