# How can I determine why this code is outputting nothing?

Tags: javascript, debugging, animation

I'm learning JavaScript animations. I wrote this code but it's not working. How can I find the problem? I want to move blue square when I click the button:

```
    <html>

    <!-- css code -->
    <style>
        body{background-color:black;}
        
        #a{
        width:100;
        height:100;
        position:relative;
        background-color:yellow;
        }
        
        #b{
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        position:absolute;
        background-color:blue;
        }
        
        #btn{
        background-color:orange;
        border-radius:4px;
        color:white;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- css ends here -->





    <!-- html code-->
    <body>
        <button type="submit" onclick="rn" id="btn">click me</button>
        <div id="a">
            <div id="b"></div>
        </div>    
    </body>
    <!-- html ends here -->





    <!-- script starts here -->
    <script>
        function rn(){
        var box = document.getElementById("b");
        var pos = 0;
        var r = setInterval(move, 5);
        
        function move(){
        if (pos == 150){clearInterval(r)
        }//if ends
        
        else{
            pos +=1;
            box.style.left = pos+"px"
        }//else ends
        }//child function ends
        }//parent function ends
    </script>
    <!-- script ends here -->


    </html>
```

Comment: Change `onclick="rn"` to `onclick="rn()"`.

Comment: Duplicate of [Radio button onclick not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32139849/4642212).

Comment: I'm not sure if the style or the script is going to work - they are neither in a `<head>` or a `<body>`.

Answer (score 2):

just change rn to rn() in click. it will work.

rn is function and you want to execute when click.